# Django select_for_update when row doesn't exist yet

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

Can you use Django's `select_for_update` to lock a row *that doesn't exist yet* to lock that row from other threads reading it while you create and then save a model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: no, you cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

When you make an insert with another thread, the database blocks another insert transaction as long as there is conflict by a constraint (primary key, unique index, etc.)